# Is Spring Boot WebClient OAuth2 client_credentials supported?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I'm trying to create a Spring Boot REST application that has to make a remote REST call to another Spring Boot application protected by OAuth2 (with grant type client_credentials).

The first application is using the **Reactive WebClient** to make the call to the second OAuth2 REST application.

I've configured the the WebClient with grant_type "client_credentials" (see code below)

```
public WebClient messageWebClient(
        ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
        OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients,
        ClientHttpConnector clientHttpConnector
) {

    ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
            new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);

    oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("message");

    return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(MESSAGE_BASE_URL)
            .clientConnector(clientHttpConnector)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .filter(oauth)
            .filter(logRequest())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ClientRegistrationRepository  clientRegistrations() {
    ClientRegistration clientRegistration = ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("message")
            .clientId("client")
            .clientSecret("secret")
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
            .tokenUri("http://localhost:8081/oauth/token")
            .build();

    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
}
```

But every time I'm making a Postman call to the first application I end up with the following exception:

**"IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Authorization Grant Type (client_credentials) for Client Registration with Id: ..."** from the *DefaultOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver*

[image]

Is "client_credentials" really supported for WebClient... or am I missing something ?

Regards

- First Application code:
  https://github.com/fdlessard/SpringBootOauth2WebClient
- SecondApplication code: 
  https://github.com/fdlessard/SpringBootOAuth2Message
- SpringBoot Version 2.1.4
- spring-security-oauth2-client: 5.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: In the documentation is `.apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())` used instead of  `.filter(oauth)`. Why do you is it in another way?

Comment: I tried the .apply .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())  instead of .filter(oauth) and it started to  work .... well partially  1 times out of two ... in debug mode. Made some progress. Thanks

Comment: Can you add the full stack? That looks like it should be successful, and I don't think its failing because of client code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I was finally able to make my code work.

... and yes, the WebClient does support OAuth2 with client_credential (well partially).

To solve my problems **I had to disable oauth2 auto configuration** and create my own implementation of **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**.

The reason I say "partially" is because the current version of spring security (5.1.x) for WebClient does not ask for a new token once the token expires (for client credential). Only with version 5.2.0.M2 or (M1) it ask for a new token when the token is expired.

Thank you  :)

Comment: care to share how did you do that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `.apply(oauth.oauth2Configuration())` instead of `.filter(oauth)`, see [`ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/web/reactive/function/client/ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.html):

> Provides an easy mechanism for using an `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` to make OAuth2 requests by including the token as a Bearer Token. It also provides mechanisms for looking up the `OAuth2AuthorizedClient`. This class is intended to be used in a servlet environment. Example usage:
>
> ```java
> OAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2 = new OAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientService);
> WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
>     .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
>     .build();
> Mono response = webClient
>     .get()
>     .uri(uri)
>     .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(authorizedClient))
>     // ...
>     .retrieve()
>     .bodyToMono(String.class);
> ```

and [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/servlet-webclient.html#servlet-webclient-setup):

> **13.1 WebClient OAuth2 Setup**
>
> The first step is ensuring to setup the WebClient correctly. An example of setting up WebClient in a servlet environment can be found below:
>
> ```java
> @Bean
> WebClient webClient(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
>         OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients) {
>     ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth =
>             new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients);
>     // (optional) explicitly opt into using the oauth2Login to provide an access token implicitly
>     // oauth.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
>     // (optional) set a default ClientRegistration.registrationId
>     // oauth.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("client-registration-id");
>     return WebClient.builder()
>             .apply(oauth2.oauth2Configuration())
>             .build();
> }
> ```