# Client credentials with Spring OAuth

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, oauth-2.0

I am trying to add authorization to the application using client credentials.

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
class CompanyScoringAuthClient {
    
    @Bean
    fun oAuth2ClientManager(clientRegistrations: ClientRegistrationRepository): OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager {
        val clientService = InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrations)
        return AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(clientRegistrations, clientService)
    }

    @Bean
    fun authRestTemplate(clientManager: OAuth2AuthorizedClientManager): RestTemplate {
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        restTemplate.interceptors.add {  request, body, execution ->
            val authorizeRequest = OAuth2AuthorizeRequest
                .withClientRegistrationId("siam")
                .principal("anon")
                .build()
            val client = clientManager.authorize(authorizeRequest)

            request.headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer ${client!!.accessToken.tokenValue}")
            execution.execute(request, body) }
        return restTemplate
    }

}
```

Properties:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          siam:
            client-id: ***********
            client-secret: ***********
            provider: keycloak
            authorization-grant-type: client_credentials

        provider:
          keycloak:
            jwk-set-uri: ***********
            token-uri: ***********
```

But every time I get an error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Invalid Authorization Grant Type (client_credentials) for Client Registration with Id: siam
```

Tried `webflux`, different configurations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Spring Boot WebClient OAuth2 client\_credentials supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55894460/is-spring-boot-webclient-oauth2-client-credentials-supported)